# Magento Filter Products By Attributes AND Tag

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to filter a collection of products based on 2 custom attributes AND a tag, I can filter by the custom attributes easily with:

```
$Products   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$Products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$Products->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute1' , 50);
$Products->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute2' , 20);
```

However when I try to extend the filter using a tag:

```
$Products->joinTable
        (
            array( 'relation'=>'tag/relation' ),
                "relation.product_id = e.entity_id AND relation.tag_id = '82'"
        );
```

I get the following message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid joint fields'

How can I get all the products that match all the conditions (custom attributes and tag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$Products->getSelect()->join(
    array('relation' => $Products->getTable('tag/relation')),
    "relation.product_id = e.entity_id AND relation.tag_id = '82'"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a third parameter to the `joinTable` method. It should contain the fields to select from the joined table. Something like this:

```
$Products->joinTable
(
    array( 'relation'=>'tag/relation' ),
    "relation.product_id = e.entity_id AND relation.tag_id = '82'",
    array('*') //all fields
);
```

Comment: I have tried that already, it fails with message: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid attribute name: e.entity_id AND relation.tag_id' =/